# Appending hash/fragment to RedirectResult results in cumbersome code

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.0, asp.net-core-mvc-2.0

The code works but is silly.

When the View is returned to the user the page scrolls to the companyId anchor.

Silly is that I have to expose another **public** action with  **another route** (without 'terms')

I want to redirect to /terms/companyId but then I get an ambigiousAction exception that this action with same routes already exists...

How to solve that dilemma if possible not change the first route?

```
[HttpGet("~/terms/{companyId}")]
public IActionResult Home(string companyId})
{
    string url = Url.Action(nameof(HomeForRedirect), new { companyId}) + "#conditions";
    return new RedirectResult(url);
}

[HttpGet("{companyId}")]
public IActionResult HomeForRedirect(string companyId)
{
    Viewbag.CompanyId = companyId;
    return View(nameof(Home));
}
```

Comment: The hash is typically a client side thing. So I think it should be present in the link that you click to get there and not be set in the HomeController.

Comment: Thanks I totally forget that it really works and was so focused on appended the hash server side because I found many posts about it on SO and thought that it must be a solution, but actually its a cumbersome solution :-), thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding your code, you essentially want the URL `/terms/{companyId}` to redirect to `/{controller}/{companyId}#conditions`? The easiest path would be to attach both routes to the same action and do the redirect in a conditional. Something like:

```
[HttpGet("{companyId}", Order = 1)]
[HttpGet("~/terms/{companyId}", Order = 2)]
public IActionResult Home(string companyId)
{
    if (Context.Request.Path.StartsWith("/terms"))
    {
        var url = Url.Action(nameof(Home), new { companyId }) + "#conditions";
        return Redirect(url);
    }

    ViewBag.CompanyId = companyId;
    return View();
}
```

An even better method would be to simply do the redirect directly in IIS. There's a not insignificant amount of processing that needs to occur to handle a request in ASP.NET Core machinery, and it's totally wasted effort simply to redirect. Use the URL Rewrite module in IIS to set up your redirect for this URL, and then your application doesn't have to worry about it at all. You just have your normal run-of-the-mill `Home` action that returns a view, and everything will just work.

A few other notes since it seems like you're new to this:

- It's better to use the `Route` attribute rather than the more specific `HttpGet` etc. The default is GET.
- Return the controller methods like `Redirect` rather than instances of `IActionResult` (i.e. `new RedirectResult(...)`).
- The default is to return a view the same name as the action. So, assuming your action is `Home`, you can just do `return View()`, rather than `return View(nameof(Home))`.

Comment: thanks for the tips but please see my above comment. You wrote that much that I have to upvote your answer Or I have a bad feeling ;-)